# How to use a Checkbox in ApplescriptObjC correctly?

Tags: applescript

I have a Programm with the function to create folders
and you can check if you need this or that folder.
And to use that I used properties with bindings to a checkbox like:

```
property checkbox : true
```

Now when the checkbox in Xcode is bounded to checkbox I can see that the checkbox.
Is there a possibility that the checkbox in the program is off and you can turn it on?

When `property checkbox : false` the program don't create Folders.

```
property checkbox : false
```

Here the full Code without property:

```
if checkbox is true then
make new folder at desktop with properties {name:"My Files"}
end if
```

Thanks for your support! </>

Answer (score 0):

Cocoa methods return Cocoa values.  The value for the checkbox is 0 or 1 (the button’s `intValue`), so you just need to coerce it, for example `if (checkbox as boolean)`.  If you are wanting to change the value programmatically, to keep KVO compliance you need to use a setter, for example `set my checkbox to false`(or use the button’s `setIntValue`).